# Infinite loop with store and http with ngFor

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have infinite loop with this code:
Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of service.dataLoadAsync() | async">
```

Service:

```
dataLoadAsync(filters: FinishedCallsFilter = {}): Observable<FinishedCall[]> {
    return this.httpFinishedCallsObservable(Object.assign({limit: this.limit}, {})).flatMap(response => {
        this.store.dispatch(new ReplaceMany(response.items))
        return this.store
    })
}
```

Also I tried this function realization:

```
dataLoadAsync(filters: FinishedCallsFilter = {}): Observable<FinishedCall[]> {
   this.httpFinishedCallsObservable(Object.assign({limit: this.limit}, {}))
        .subscribe(response => this.store.dispatch(new ReplaceMany(response.items)))
    return this.store
}

private httpFinishedCallsObservable(params: { limit: number, tag ?: string }) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, params)
        .map((json) => this.parseHttp(json))
        .do(response => this.tagStore.dispatch(new UpdateTag(response.tag)))
}
```

So, the problem. Without http request, evferything is fine. But then I try to download data and update store, `dataLoadAsync` function calls a lot of times in loop.
How to fix the code? I want to use store for cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually an infinite loop.

If you bind a function in the template, the function is called every time Angular change detection runs.

This is bad practice in general. Instead assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead.

```
constructor() {
  this.data = service.dataLoadAsync();
}
```

and

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of service.data | async">
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Have the same issue even when using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (thought this would prevent that?), and binding a function to the template which returns a `pluck`ed `http.get` response. Subscribing to the http response and assigning that to a property seems to work.